# Event not firing in published version

Tags: c#, events, remote-desktop

So I'm making a desktop app to connect to a remote desktop.
I wan't to fire an event when I get connected to the remote desktop and when I'm disconnected again. For this I used:

```
rdp.OnDisconnected += (sender, e) => { RDPConnectionDetection.Disconnect(accMeth, CustomerList, rdpDictionary, grMainWindow); EndBusyIndicator(); };
rdp.OnConnected += (sender, e) => { RDPConnectionDetection.Connect(host, grMainWindow, CustomerList, accMeth); EndBusyIndicator(); };
```

The version of the RDP client I'm currently using is AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting But I've tried later versions.

The problem is that these events fire when I test them in visual studio 2015, but not when I'm running the app published on my PC.

So I tried using different versions of the AxMsRdpClient, I event tried just adding it and letting it auto gen the method  as stated below.

```
rdp.OnConnected += Rdp_OnConnected;
private void Rdp_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It works");
}
```

But none have been successful. 
Would anyone know how to fix the issue or be able to guide me in the good direction? 
Thank you!